# Búsqueda de celdas vecinas en un solo pase

Tags: c++

Necesito desarrollar un algoritmo que me detecte las celdas de una rejilla que estén conectadas. Considerando como conectadas toda celda que esté a distancia 1 horizontal o verticalmente (no diagonalmente). Si dispongo de estos datos:

```
struct cell
{
    int x{}, y{};
};

using group = std::list<cell>;

group cells =
{
    {0,6},{0,7},
    {1,1},{1,2},{1,4},{1,6},{1,7},
    {2,1},{2,4},
    {3,3},{3,4},
    {4,3},{4,4},
    {5,0},{5,1},{5,2},{5,5},{5,6},{5,7},
    {6,0},{6,1},{6,2},{6,5},{6,7},
    {7,0},{7,1},{7,2},{7,5},{7,6},{7,7}, 
};
```

Que en una rejilla 7×7 se verían así:

> ```
>   01234567
> 0       ##
> 1  ## # ##
> 2  #  #
> 3    ##
> 4    ##
> 5 ###  ###
> 6 ###  # #
> 7 ###  ###
> ```

Debería dar como resultado cinco grupos de celdas conectadas:

1. `{0, 6}`, `{1, 6}`, `{0, 7}`, `{1, 7}`.
2. `{1, 1}`, `{1, 2}`, `{2, 1}`.
3. `{1, 4}`, `{2, 4}`, `{3, 3}`, `{3, 4}`, `{4, 3}`, `{4, 4}`.
4. `{5, 0}`, `{5, 1}`, `{5, 2}`, `{6, 0}`, `{6, 1}`, `{6, 2}`, `{7, 0}`, `{7, 1}`, `{7, 2}`.
5. `{5, 5}`, `{5, 6}`, `{5, 7}`, `{6, 5}`, `{6, 7}`, `{7, 5}`, `{7, 6}`, `{7, 7}`.

El algoritmo debe hacer el mínimo posible de comparaciones celda contra celda, de ahí que surja la idea de un solo pase. Mi primer intento es el siguiente:

```
int count = 0;

int distance(const cell &a, const cell &b)
{
    const auto dx = b.x - a.x;
    const auto dy = b.y - a.y;
    return (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
}

bool near(const cell &a, const cell &b)
{
    ++count;
    return distance(a, b) == 1;
}

void nearby(group &source, group &target)
{
    for (auto b = target.begin(), e = target.end(); b != e; ++b)
    {
        if (auto found = std::find_if(source.begin(), source.end(), [b = *b](const auto &a)
        {
            return near(a, b);
        });
            found != source.end())
        {
            target.emplace_back(*found);
            source.erase(found);
            b = target.begin();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::list<group> b;

    while (cells.size())
    {
        group t{cells.back()};
        cells.pop_back();
        nearby(cells, t);
        b.emplace_back(std::move(t));
    }

    std::cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

La función `nearby` recibe dos grupos de celdas (`source` y `target`) y busca las celdas de `source` cercanas a las de `target` y las mueve allí. Esto implica que cada vez que se añade una celda deben volverse a revisar todas las celdas de `target` lo que da como resultado 1199 comparaciones (casi cuarenta comparaciones por celda).

Así que he probado una estrategia diferente:

```
std::list<group> blobs(group g)
{
    std::list<group> result;

    while (g.size())
    {
        const auto b = g.front();
        g.pop_front();

        if (auto found = std::find_if(result.begin(), result.end(), [&b](const auto &g)
        {
            return std::any_of(g.begin(), g.end(), [&b](const auto &a) { return near(a, b); });
        });
            found != result.end())
        {
            found->push_back(b);
        }
        else
        {
            result.emplace_back(group{b});
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

La función `blobs` también mantiene una lista de grupos de celdas, por cada celda a clasificar mira si está cerca de al menos una celda de cada uno de los grupos ya creados y la mueve ahí, esto da como resultado 380 comparaciones (algo más de doce comparaciones por celda) que es considerablemente menor a 1199 pero agrupa las celdas mal:

1. `{0, 6}`, `{0, 7}`, `{1, 6}`, `{1, 7}`.
2. `{1, 1}`, `{1, 2}`, `{2, 1}`.
3. `{1, 4}`, `{2, 4}`, `{3, 4}`, `{4, 4}`.
4. `{3, 3}`, `{4, 3}`.
5. `{5, 0}`, `{5, 1}`, `{5, 2}`, `{6, 0}`, `{6, 1}`, `{6, 2}`, `{7, 0}`, `{7, 1}`, `{7, 2}`.
6. `{5, 5}`, `{5, 6}`, `{5, 7}`, `{6, 5}`, `{6, 7}`, `{7, 5}`, `{7, 6}`, `{7, 7}`.

El grupo tres y cuatro son el mismo pero por la ordenación de las celdas cuando se intentó agrupar la celda `{3, 3}` la que es su celda vecina `{3, 4}` aún no estaba agrupada, así que se consideró que `{3, 3}` no tenía vecinas y la metió en un grupo propio.

Se pueden ver los diferentes algoritmos en TIO: <kbd>[1199 comparaciones](https://tio.run/##hVTbbtswDH2Ov4LrgMRu1CBJGwfIpS992EesQyHJSirMsQxb7uIZ/vVlFOXc2mIDDNnkEQ95SMkyz@@2Uh4OX3Um0ypRsNKmtIXiu8fg7Et1aS9tW@WpunTwdGsKbV8xKsDwSlqQKk2DJujpzMK@aRnUTbsM8AmqUmdb2BamymENpU0WC5dg5SIeEXcR0lS4rmGMtjAmBZOrgltTrEJpstLTQ58zuDRF1GugULYqMs9rtQr5aM@Aj@oIVmencE6BziW0rmR0d7qhf0q1Ct8B19lkBKdsBlYrGDQD95KjvXvdMLjxZk1gO6BcTl2Ccnkm1b@1uO55D6@sgWSP/cC64Q7V7JfXWE1YTViNWFdWiEG3GBnBEL9r942Sg7ZraqZ48f8ahkOaxpn1VD5uFxGs1zAhTj9SF1rC2kU2Yxa3DNd5y9CasAlaEzal9YHWmFaPTwmfOgSte3aP1n1nPZD10FkzNkZrRvtnxDdjM1pjWj1fTLti2hXTrph2xR0@J3xO@JzwOeFzYpm7XUAn9s3ohJol6tCL7JemKqRi3THuW15slaV2bUwBIU1F4FA8MBJqq7MwYqDOPpUlIZ4/AV/WoJYwHGK7e0jQ05uOYIN9T453ZKOz5EVvQp/5zNjZxMbgu0t6K36EF6ejz5GYmI8TpMHT9HCqvZbWns@GxVwyniKPRe/ylEv1Irj8Gd5SiI8@BhW8VOGF/2MTKGWAT3cbdtx5XevO/wJq6yMIbL734hG0dKueVJrwcgE3y67Vl0Llwh8/V/VVmKQrCAPH9@tVpwrj3MZRqX8rUulE@mHaxkMkMWpdud6Rm9zrJgndeSCIgSWfuO4PlbAzbyq0kcNR8MeaRWoELOA4/Gu1z9m3osoNyQ16nwh2kUgQ0Qg@V0xp39M@mV3OCy61yZTrJoXQT9eFPWfUqe604E@4PRz@yE3Kt@XhDqnWcjic8r8)</kbd> y <kbd>[380 comparaciones](https://tio.run/##hVTbbptAEH2Gr5imkg0NQXYSg@Rgv@ShH9FU1rIsBBXvIi6qKeLb3dlZbONcWskemDkzs3M5Cy/Lu4zz4/FrLnnRJgKiXNVNJdh@a19sRV43U71py0JMDazIVJU3rxhlY3jLG@CiKOzetnLZwKEfPOj64cnGn93Wucwgq1RbwgbqJlmv9QGRjtgiriO4alFuYIF6rFQBqhQVa1QVOVzJ2qSHGfNgqsau1UMlmraSJm@TC4f5Bw@Y37kQXYyxNsZofIJBl4zmsW@YnY@KnDfA9WnchfNpCqII5v1cP7h/0I8bD26M2hE4zOks3V2C7TLJxb970dMzFtY2CpIDzgPrhjvs5vB0jXWEdYR1iI1lORj0DSNduMX3Tr9jy/YwDlUKVv2/httb2sYl67l8dI9d2GxgSTnNSnVoDRsd2S@8YPBQhoOH2tJborb07kk@kgxIGvye8HuNoPbgPaD2MGqPpD2O2spboLYi/xXlW3krkgFJky8gr4C8AvIKyCsY8ZDwkPCQ8JDwkLKE2guIsReOUotbiAsV147pN6MhvXOpRN0WOLQRwhE2xIpnUSSsXsMNzjNVFTiTNc742ozPta3rME4UgrnO9/s1LwQ4mV/nf4Tjoi@eP2VDjGTI/LRSsnFw25aV@aUqd2cDWvIUHPJNcbXJ6RqmuUx2eeqY2v1YZLl0XG/sxRcy0dqPWfzzqupMl6trsKZ3j8lup1Is85wm@zQDm1wlIiUxC@8LlW@kZUr9srkq53w0oXfbsq1fdzHjv5zYxOJfFLW4VGhi92XBuDCetLE@Hk4BSOVTJ6ctjhd3z3QnH@471nN9t1BNFFiPfDGrHfd1zYoX@b1qS2V4YVsfMGPMovv9jBpU@Nu8z2pfsorxXEmh01MIfV112IskSo3d4td2OB7/Ag)</kbd>.

¿De qué manera puedo hacer la búsqueda de celdas vecinas minimizando las comparaciones y obteniendo los grupos adecuados?

Answer (score 2):

**Primera aproximación**

Suponiendo que las celdas pueden venir desordenadas, una forma de proceder puede pasar por definir un rectángulo que incluye a cada grupo. De esta forma podemos comprobar rápidamente si una celda cae cerca del grupo o no:

- Si la celda no está en la frontera del grupo o dentro del mismo la ignoramos.
- Si la celda está en la frontera del grupo o dentro procedemos a comparar las celdas del grupo una a una.

Dicho con código:

```
bool isInRange(int value, int min, int max)
{
  return value >= min && value <= max;
}

std::list<group> eferionFunc(group g)
{
  cell topLeft, bottomRight;

  std::list<group> result;

  while( g.size() )
  {
    const auto b = g.front();
    g.pop_front();
    cell topLeft = b;
    cell bottomRight = b;

    group currentGroup;
    currentGroup.push_back(b);

    for( auto it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); )
    {
      cell currentCell = *it;
      if( isInRange(currentCell.x, topLeft.x-1, bottomRight.x+1) && isInRange(currentCell.y, topLeft.y-1, bottomRight.y+1) )
      {
        if( std::any_of(currentGroup.begin(), currentGroup.end(), [&currentCell ](const auto &a) { return near(a, currentCell); }) )
        {
          currentGroup.push_back(currentCell);
          topLeft     = { std::min(topLeft.x, currentCell.x),     std::min(topLeft.y, currentCell.y) };
          bottomRight = { std::max(bottomRight.x, currentCell.x), std::max(bottomRight.y, currentCell.y) };
          it = g.erase(it);
          continue;
        }
      }
      ++it;
    }
    result.push_back(currentGroup);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Esto debería reducir el número de comparaciones respecto a la versión `blob`, como así sucede:

```
Grupos: {0, 6} {0, 7} {1, 6} {1, 7} 
Grupos: {1, 1} {1, 2} {2, 1} 
Grupos: {1, 4} {2, 4} {3, 4} {4, 4} 
Grupos: {3, 3} {4, 3} 
Grupos: {5, 0} {5, 1} {5, 2} {6, 0} {6, 1} {6, 2} {7, 0} {7, 1} {7, 2} 
Grupos: {5, 5} {5, 6} {5, 7} {6, 5} {6, 7} {7, 5} {7, 6} {7, 7} 
Comparaciones: 73
```

Y está claro que comparar enteros es mucho más ligero que andar haciendo multiplicaciones ...

El problema es que sigue adoleciendo de ciertos problemas a la hora de crear los grupos. Básicamente es incapaz de fusionar grupos ya existentes.. de ahí que salga un grupo de más.

**Segunda aproximación**

Cambiamos el planteamiento. Ahora vamos a crear un mapa de regiones. Lo que vamos a hacer ahora es comprobar si cada celda linda o no con alguna región ya existente... si es así añadimos dicha celda a la región y, si no, creamos una región nueva.

Puede suceder que una celda sirva como punto de unión para dos o más regiones ya existentes... en este caso podemos aprovechar para fusionar todas estas regiones.

Esta función es un poco más extensa:

```
std::list<group> eferionFunc2(group g)
{
  std::map<cell, int> cellsMap;

  std::map<int, group> groups;

  int groupCounter = 0;
  // First step: grouping some cells
  for( cell const& currentCell : g )
  {
    std::set<int> nearGroups;

    if( auto it = cellsMap.find({currentCell.x-1, currentCell.y}); it  != cellsMap.end() )
    {
      nearGroups.insert(it->second);
    }

    if( auto it = cellsMap.find({currentCell.x+1, currentCell.y}); it != cellsMap.end() )
    {
      nearGroups.insert(it->second);
    }

    if( auto it = cellsMap.find({currentCell.x, currentCell.y-1}); it != cellsMap.end() )
    {
      nearGroups.insert(it->second);
    }

    if( auto it = cellsMap.find({currentCell.x, currentCell.y+1}); it != cellsMap.end() )
    {
      nearGroups.insert(it->second);
    }

    int currentGroupIndex = -1;
    if( nearGroups.empty() )
    {
      currentGroupIndex = groupCounter++;
    }
    else if( nearGroups.size() == 1 )
    {
      currentGroupIndex = *nearGroups.begin();
    }
    else if( nearGroups.size() > 1 )
    {
      currentGroupIndex = *nearGroups.begin();
      auto & currentGroup = groups[currentGroupIndex];
      for( auto it = std::next(nearGroups.begin(), 1); it != nearGroups.end(); ++it )
      {
        auto & groupToRemove = groups[*it];
        currentGroup.insert(currentGroup.end(), groupToRemove.begin(), groupToRemove.end());
        groups.erase(*it);

        for( auto & pair : cellsMap )
        {
          if( pair.second == *it)
            pair.second = currentGroupIndex;
        }
      }
    }

    cellsMap.insert({currentCell, currentGroupIndex });
    groups[currentGroupIndex].push_back(currentCell);
  }

  std::list<group> result;
  for( auto & pair : groups )
    result.insert(result.begin(), pair.second);
  return result;
}
```

Pero a cambio calcula los grupos correctamente y, lo mejor de todo... **no calcula distancia entre celdas**

```
Grupos: {5, 5} {5, 6} {5, 7} {6, 5} {6, 7} {7, 5} {7, 6} {7, 7} 
Grupos: {5, 0} {5, 1} {5, 2} {6, 0} {6, 1} {6, 2} {7, 0} {7, 1} {7, 2} 
Grupos: {1, 4} {2, 4} {3, 3} {3, 4} {4, 3} {4, 4} 
Grupos: {1, 1} {1, 2} {2, 1} 
Grupos: {0, 6} {0, 7} {1, 6} {1, 7} 
Comparaciones: 0
```

Adicionalmente, esta función parece comportarse ligeramente mejor que las otras alternativas (en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución).

No es perfecta y seguramente sea mejorable. Se aceptan sugerencias.

Comment: Las propuestas me gustan, pero es difícil saber si son más eficientes sin hacer mediciones. El problema es que se ha trasladado el peso de la computación de la función `near` al operador `<` o a la función `IsInRange`. La función `eferionFunc` lama 73 veces a `near` y 172 veces a `IsInRange` mientras que `eferionFunc2` llama 828 veces al operador `<`.

Comment: Está claro que la complejidad la vas a desplazar a unas funciones o a otras... pero el operador `<` es infinitamente más liviano que `near`. Tampoco es un código optimizado, por ejemplo si añades los elementos al inicio del `std::list` en vez de al final y quizás si se usa `unordered_map` en vez de `map`... todo dependerá del número de nodos a tratar. Pero en una pasada, como pretendes, va a estar complicado ya que vas a tener que ser capaz de fusionar grupos... y para ello tienes que saber antes si una celda une dos o más grupos... ¿cómo lo haces con una única comprobación?

Comment: No veo que `<` sea más liviano que `near`, estoy haciendo pruebas y para 10 operaciones `near`  es ~13 veces más lento que `<`, para 100 `<` es ~4 veces más lento que `near` y para 1000 `<` es ~11 veces más lento que `near`. Es decir, a más operaciones más rápido es `near` respecto `<`. Por otro lado ten en cuenta que `<` se llama **dos veces** en `map` y `set` por cada comprobación de equidad.

Comment: [Benchmarks](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ns8a59nhwgSDEO83).

Comment: Estoy viendo que con O3 la diferencia de rendimiento entre `<` y `near` es casi nula.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster [enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eTmFdRuQ28SxT1cy) Si pruebas los algoritmos en si la cosa cambia. Por cierto nota que no has inicializado las variables `n` y `l` que toman los tiempos de los test

Comment: ¿Cómo se me ha podido pasar inicializar `n` y `l`? (facepalm).

Comment: ¡Un momento! En los benchmarks que me has pasado ¿los algoritmos iniciales tienen mejor rendimiento que los finales? ¿¡incluidas optimizaciones!?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no te entiendo. Con pocas celdas `nearby` es el que mejor funciona... con 100 es el que peor tiempos da ... y con 1000 ya se muere del todo

Comment: He tomado varias medidas y en general [`nearby` y `blobs` están respondiendo mejor](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KInILRlZ-7XXwf28OfHHhOnwowOMGGagk8IU7yR83bY/edit?usp=sharing) ¿he tomado mal las medidas?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ni idea... entiendo también que los resultados pueden depender del compilador utilizado y del sistema sobre el que se compile